# USB wireless adapter driver for linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, firmware

I'm trying to connect an Atheros ar1021x (ath6kl family) USB-Wireless adapter to a Raspberry Pi (with 4.14 kernel).

My vendor provided a copy of driver source code, but it is for kernel 3.18. It does not compile on my Raspberry Pi due to the kernel API change.

But I noticed that kernel 4.14 has already integrated driver for ath6kl family. And the `dmesg` log contains

```
[    4.370769] ath6kl: Failed to get board file ath6k/AR6004/hw3.0/bdata.bin (-2), trying to find default board file.
[    4.692766] ath6kl: Failed to init ath6kl core: -2
```

I guess that this ar1021x chip requires `AR6004/hw3.0/bdata.bin` file, and that [ar1021x is similar to ar9374x and ar6004x](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Atheros). I found `hw3.0` [here](https://github.com/qca/ath6kl-firmware/tree/master/ath6k/AR6004/hw3.0). So I copied the `hw3.0` directory to `/lib/firmware/ath6k/AR6004/`. In this directory, there already exists `hw1.2` and `hw1.3`.

- Now comes my first question, what does `hw1.2`, `hw1.3` and `hw3.0` mean? And how does the system determine which `hw` is required to boot the ar1021x chip?
- And in the `hw3.0` directory, these is a `fw-5.bin` file. Is this `5` some version number?

---

After reboot, I can get a new interface `wlan1` in `ifconfig`. However, the flags of this interface is `flags=4099<UP, BROADCAST, MULTICAST>`, without `RUNNING`. And the tx-power given by `iwconfig` is 0 dBm. I tried to use `sudo iwconfig wlan1 txpower 20` to change the transmission power, but it errors with

```
Error for wireless request "Set Tx Power" (8B26) :
    SET failed on device wlan1 ; Operation not supported.
```

I can use `sudo wiliest wlan1 scanning` to find some access points, but I have no way to join these AP. I tried the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, it does not work. I also tried to disable the on-board wireless adapter of Raspberry Pi, it does not help either.

Here are some messages may help:

`dmesg | grep ath` output:

```
[   10.101457] ath6kl: htc pipe control receive timeout!
[   10.101466] ath6kl: htc wait target timed out, resetting device
[   10.101951] ath6kl: Failed to start hardware: -110
[   10.102079] ath6kl: Failed to init ath6kl core: -110
[   10.102406] ath6kl_usb: probe of 1-1.1.2:1.0 failed with error -110
[   10.102526] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath6kl_usb
[   11.942056] ath6kl: ar6004 hw 3.0 usb fw 3.5.0.349-1 api 5
[   11.942067] ath6kl: firmware supports: 64bit-rates,map-lp-endpoint,ratetable-mcs15,no-ip-checksum
[   11.942696] ath6kl: Firmware lacks RSN-CAP-OVERRIDE, so HT (802.11n) is disabled.
```

`lsusb -v` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:9374 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0cf3 Atheros Communications, Inc.
  idProduct          0x9374 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          118
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              200mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           9
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

`sudo lshw -C network` output:

```
  *-network:0               
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: b8:27:eb:e7:c4:28
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.154 firmware=01-4fbe0b04 ip=192.168.1.102 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlan1
       serial: 20:32:33:af:4b:7b
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=usb driverversion=4.14.98-v7+ firmware=3.5.0.349-1 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: eth0
       serial: b8:27:eb:b2:91:7d
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=lan78xx driverversion=1.0.6 duplex=half link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

- So, what's wrong with this, and how to get the ar1021x chip work?

Comment: Did you install firmware-atheros? I just arrived to the same error and someone told me to that. I did it, I plugged and played.